# Animate "height" Jquery on the bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height, direction

I want to animate my banners, but here, they're animate by the top, and I want that the animation begin by the bottom. That the orange banners disapear by the bottom.
It's possible ?

--> **[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDhzJ/11/)** <--

```
$(".myDiv").mouseover(function() {  
$('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({height: '0px'}); });
$(".myDiv").mouseout(function() {  
$('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({height: '50px'}); });
```

Comment: So you essentially want them to shrink down instead of shrink up?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do what I think you are, try the following jQuery :

```
$(".myDiv").mouseover(function() {  
    $('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({height: '0px', top: '50px'}); 
});
$(".myDiv").mouseout(function() {  
    $('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({height: '50px', top: '0px'}); 
});
```

This will animate the height and the CSS `Top` position of the element. This will make it seem like the element is stuck to the bottom and is shrinking down.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffHNF/1/)